# SAS - Group By not working due to case statement in Select

Tags: sql, sas

I have an issue where some SAS code using PROC SQL isn't working as there is a case statement around one of my calculations.

The code looks like the below:

```
PROC SQL;
create table example as
select
a.var1,
a.var2,
a.var3,
case when a.NumericVariable is not missing then
Max(0,Sum(Sum(a.Var4), -Sum(a.Var5)))) end as Calculation
from table1 a inner join table2 b
on a.primarykey=b.primarykey
group by var1,var2,var3;
quit;
```

This code returns duplicated rows for the number of rows in table A.
Removing the case statement as below:

```
PROC SQL;
create table example as
select
a.var1,
a.var2,
a.var3,
Max(0,Sum(Sum(a.Var4), -Sum(a.Var5)))) as Calculation
from table1 a inner join table2 b
on a.primarykey=b.primarykey
group by var1,var2,var3;
quit;
```

This just returns the group by using the levels of var1,var2 and var3.

How do I adjust the upper code to remove the duplicates?

Comment: I think you leave out something important- what `calculation` is.  I try to address that in my answer, but your question would be better if it included an example of that.  It's possible in particular that you're using `sum` or some other function that is both a summary function and a row level function, and that is causing some of your issue.

Comment: I concur, what exactly is in the calculation field may matter as well if any of the variables are formatted and you're expecting SQL to honour formats. That's usually a big gotcha in SQL as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by performing the `case` statement *inside* the summary.  This only works if it's *possible* to do that, though - you might have to rework your query to make it possible.

If you can't put the `case` statement inside the summarization, *and* the `case` statement is using a variable that isn't in the group by (and can't be put in the group by), then it's not possible to do what you want here - you have to change something else, maybe preprocess the data.

One example is, if you want to only include a non-zero value if `var6` is not missing, but you're okay with zero in that case, then this works:

```
PROC SQL;
create table example as
select
a.var1,
a.var2,
a.var3,
max(0,sum(sum(case when a.var6 is not missing then a.var4 end),-(sum(case when a.var6 is not missing then a.var5 end)))) as Calculation
from table1 a inner join table2 b
on a.primarykey=b.primarykey
group by var1,var2,var3;
quit;
```

Here's an example that works using `sashelp.class`:

```
proc sql;
  select max(0,sum(sum(case when age > 13 then height else 0 end),
               sum(case when age > 13 then weight else 0 end))
             )
    from sashelp.class
    group by sex;
quit;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for Your contributions here. The calculation above was not a variable but an actual calculation (specifically Max(0,Sum(Sum(a.Var4), -Sum(a.Var5)))). I tried solution 1 but got the following error
```ERROR: Summary functions nested in this way are not supported.```
Solution 2 also errors as adding the column field number to the group by yields the following error.
```ERROR: sqlplan internal error: Cannot find symbol Calculation, var=4, tag=0003. This message can be caused by attempting to make correlated references between two different items on a single FROM clause.```

Comment: @thequadge Sounds like solution 1 is right, but you can't nest that inside a `sum` - that wasn't intended to be added to your calculation, I was just showing it as an example.

Comment: Many thanks, the above solved the issue. Many thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

You are not using any aggregation functions, so how about just using `select distinct`:

```
create table example as
    select distinct a.var1, a.var2, a.var3,
           (case when a.NumericVariable is not missing then Calculation 
            end) as Calculation
    from table1 a inner join
         table2 b
         on a.primarykey = b.primarykey;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works in my example which is great new. I am interested in the wider question of how to solve it in other cases where I wouldn't be able to use ```distinct``` ?

Comment: Gordon, I'm almost sure OP is using an aggregation function and just not describing it (probably `calculation` is not a field but something like `sum(field1)` ) - otherwise SAS will not allow the `group by` (it will convert it to `order by`) and the two code samples above would be identical in the number of rows they return.

Comment: @Joe . . . This answers the question that was actually *asked*.  If the OP has a different question, I would recommend that the OP ask a new question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think you are assuming `calculation` means the variable `calculation` though - it's clearly not, otherwise SAS wouldn't return a valid result (it would not do what was described).  In that, it'll be different from any other SQL implementation I know of.   It's a poorly phrased question, but it's not *this* question.  Either way, `distinct` solves the problem - by hiding the true issue, though (and might yield incorrect results, depending on what they're expecting from the calculation).

Comment: FYI - OP updated to clarify that `calculation` was an actual calculation.